# How to document a class which implements more than one interface?

Tags: php, return-type

Let us say you have a class

```
class View implements ViewInterface, TemplateInterface {

     private $template;

     public function setTemplate($template) {
         $this->template = $template;
         return $this;
     }
}
```

When you are then documenting the `TemplateInterface` and you come to the `setTemplate($template)` method what do you put down as its return type?

If I put `View` as the return type and then I later have different classes implementing the `TemplateInterface` which are not of type `View` my API documentation would be wrong.

Do you put down a return type of `View`, `ViewInterface`, `TemplateInterface`, or a mixture of them?

```
namespace Views\Interfaces;

interface TemplateInterface {

    /* --------------------------------- */
       public function getTemplate();
    /* ---------------------------------
     * @args: void
     *
     * @return: String - The name of the template.
    */

    /* ------------------------------------------ */
       public function setTemplate($template);
    /* ------------------------------------------
     * @arg 1: (String $template) - The name of the template file.
     *
     * @return: Not sure yet!!!
    */

}
```

Comment: Show the `TemplateInterface` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface should look like:

```
interface TemplateInterface
{
    /**
     * @return TemplateInterface
     */
    public function setTemplate($template);
}
```

And the view class:

```
class View implements ViewInterface, TemplateInterface {

     private $template;

     /**
      * @return TemplateInterface
      * or (maybe better)
      * @return View (as it implements TemplateInterface and is more specialized)
      */
     public function setTemplate($template) {
         $this->template = $template;
         return $this;
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that but when you are injecting an object into a method and that object implements an interface you put the name of the interface as the type hint for that object in the methods signature so I just have this feeling on return type why would it change and say the object type instead of the interface/s the object is implementing.

Comment: what is the return type of `TemplateInterface::setTemplate()` ?

Comment: It returns an instance of `View`. The thing is, in my API documentation I put `@return: View` and then I have a different class implementing the `TemplateInterface` it will not be of type `View` so the API would be lieing.

Comment: Then my answer is: Use `@return TemplateInterface` in the interface and in the view

Comment: @David, is the colon in that `@return` syntax correct? I've not seen that before, and in auto-completing IDEs, it is unnecessary as far as I know.

Comment: @halfer I did not know there was a correct syntax to commenting your code to be honest. This is just my way of doing it.

Comment: @David Of course you are free to use your own syntax but you should check [this](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html)

Comment: @David and [this](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-developers.html) (new version)